# python selenium web scraper

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I wrote simple web scraper which use excel file with ean codes to search on site products and take them price.
I have one big problem when i open first browser instation where I accept cookie and setup localization the shop which i want to scrap

```
driver.get("https://www.castorama.pl")
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "truste_popframe"))
time.sleep(1)
accept = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "call").click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
postcode = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "_1a41e483").send_keys("38-500")
time.sleep(1)
submit_postcode = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[normalize-space()='Dodaj']").click()
results = []
```

this works fine, but the problem starts when i want to use a function with loop to search and then this localization is not set and needs to be set again each time

```
def getdata(symbol):
    driver.get(f"https://www.castorama.pl/search?term={symbol}")
  
    name = WebDriverWait(driver,2).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "product-title"))
        )
    price = WebDriverWait(driver,2).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_5d34bd7a"))
        )
    records = {
      'ean': symbol,
      'cena': price.text,
      'name': name.text
    }
    
    return records
```

Do you have an idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `selenium` you can use their pagination API to get the results in Json form directly:

```py
import requests

params = {
    "include": "content",
    "page[number]": "1",
    "page[size]": "24",
    "searchTerm": "farba",  # <-- the search term
    "storeId": 1543         # <-- add store id here
}

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Atmosphere atmosphere_app_id=kingfisher-EPgbIZbIpBzipu0bKltAFm1xler30LKmaF4vJH96'
}

api_url = 'https://api.kingfisher.com/v2/mobile/products/CAPL'

for params['page[number]'] in range(1, 2):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    data = requests.get(api_url, params=params, headers=headers).json()
    for r in data['data']:
        a = r['attributes']
        print(f'{a["pricing"]["currentUnitPrice"]["amountIncTax"]:>8} {a["pricing"]["currencyCode"]:<4} {a["name"]}')
```

Prints:

```
   30.79 PLN  Farba Dulux EasyCare jasny spokój 2,5 l
    7.25 PLN  Farba Dekoral Ściany i Sufity 10 l + 20% gratis
    29.4 PLN  Farba Dulux EasyCare idealne cappuccino 5 l
     4.7 PLN  Farba biała mat 10 l
    20.0 PLN  Farba Dulux Ściany i Sufity najpopularniejszy szary 5 l
   25.99 PLN  Farba Dekoral Voice of Color miętowy pastelowy 2,5 l
    11.8 PLN  Farba Dulux Premium White 10 l
    29.4 PLN  Farba Dulux EasyCare designerski szary 5 l
   37.99 PLN  Farba Dulux EasyCare Kuchnia i Łazienka biały 2,5 l
   37.99 PLN  Farba Dulux EasyCare Kuchnia karmelowe latte 2,5 l
    14.8 PLN  Farba lateksowa Tikkurila Super White 10 l
   37.99 PLN  Farba Dulux EasyCare Kuchnia i Łazienka złoty pieprz 2,5 l

...and so on.
```

---

EDIT: To search by code:

```py
import requests

# store_id=1593 - warsaw
# sorte_id=1543 - wroclaw
store_id = 1543
product_id = '5908305642893'

params = {"searchTerm": f"{product_id}_CAPL", "storeId": store_id}

api_url = "https://api.kingfisher.com/v2/mobile/products/CAPL"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Atmosphere atmosphere_app_id=kingfisher-EPgbIZbIpBzipu0bKltAFm1xler30LKmaF4vJH96"
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params, headers=headers).json()
a = data["data"][0]["attributes"]
print(
    f'{a["pricing"]["currentUnitPrice"]["amountIncTax"]:>8} {a["pricing"]["currencyCode"]:<4} {a["name"]}'
)
```

Prints:

```
     0.3 PLN  Ziemia uniwersalna 50 l
```

Comment: thanks, but they have difrent price in difrent city and I need to choose localization. Can I do it with this API?

Comment: @ŁukaszTarnowski You can add `storeId` parameter to your query. You can find the `storeId` if you open Web Developer Tools -> Network Tab and change the store (there should be queries containing this Id)

Comment: I'm bad with API's. I started learning python recently. Is there any option to do this with selenium?

Comment: ok. I almost got it. But what if i want to search not by phrase like "farba" but by ean code  like "5908305642893" and for example I have 100 codes in xls file or csv and I want to check them all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
added a function and loops to search for each barcode line in the excel file. But I am only asking for a hint how to save the result in an excel file. In the previous program of this type I used pandas but I have no experience with JSON yet.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('eanCS.xlsx', dtype="int64") 
mylist = df['ean'].tolist()

store_id = 2793
product_id = mylist

def getdata(symbol):
   params = {"searchTerm": f"{symbol}_CAPL", "storeId": store_id}
   data = requests.get(api_url, params=params, headers=headers).json()
   a = data["data"][0]["attributes"]
   print(f'{a["pricing"]["currentPrice"]["amountIncTax"]:>4} {a["pricing"] 
   ["currencyCode"]:<4} {a["ean"]:<4} {a["name"]:<4} ')


api_url = "https://api.kingfisher.com/v2/mobile/products/CAPL"
headers = {
  "Authorization": "Atmosphere atmosphere_app_id=kingfisher- 
   EPgbIZbIpBzipu0bKltAFm1xler30LKmaF4vJH96"
    }
 for item in mylist:
   getdata(item)
```

Comment: You can store the price, ean, name, ... to a list, create new dataframe and use `DataFrame.to_csv` or `DataFrame.to_excel` to save it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have last question. I want to add availability of product. Can you help  me. I'm looking in atributes InStore but this doesn't work.